# Return to me the latest Transaction that the user made

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I want to get the latest Transactions of that account number by using clientid. I don't have the right solution yet.

I already try Select * From `transactions` where `accountno`= "A6B55" ORDER BY `clientids` desc LIMIT 1;

```
clientids  date   time   cardno  accountno   transactiontype   currbalance
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2019-02-26 5:18AM  865505   A6B55     withdraw         20,000

2       2019-02-26 6:15PM  865505  A6B55     deposit            30,000

3       2019-02-26 9:10PM  78805   6979A     deposit           10,0000
```

I expected to give me the latest transaction that account made. like for example as you can see on my table account no A6B55 made two transactions for this day and the clientids for that account is 1 and 2 I just want to get clientid no.2 and date,time,cardno,transactiontype and currbalance.
Thank you!

Comment: Suggestion: Make the time field of `TimeStamp` and execute command `Select * From transactions where accountno= "A6B55" ORDER BY TIME desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: Will it post 1 Account only as I required to give me the latest transaction of that account.

Comment: what is thre right query for that ? do you have suggestions?

Comment: Is time a time column a time datatype or a string or is java formatting the time (and currbalance)? Please add table definition.

Comment: There's something not quite right about this question - you are asking for 'latest transaction that account made' but all your sample dates are the same , so are you looking for the last transaction on every day for an account or the last transaction for a specific day?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution;

```
create table transactions (clientid INT PRIMARY KEY, date DATE, time TIME, CardNo INT, accountno VARCHAR(100), Transactiontype VARCHAR(20), curbalance float);

mysql> desc transactions;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| clientid        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| date            | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time            | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CardNo          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| accountno       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Transactiontype | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| curbalance      | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into transactions values(1, '2019-02-26', '05:18:00', 865505, 'A6B55', 'withdraw', 20000);
mysql> insert into transactions values(2, '2019-02-26', '18:15:00', 865505, 'A6B55', 'deposit', 30000);
mysql> insert into transactions values(3, '2019-02-26', '21:10:00', 78805, '6979A', 'deposit', 100000);

mysql> select * from transactions;
+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| clientid | date       | time     | CardNo | accountno | Transactiontype | curbalance |
+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
|        1 | 2019-02-26 | 05:18:00 | 865505 | A6B55     | withdraw        |      20000 |
|        2 | 2019-02-26 | 18:15:00 | 865505 | A6B55     | deposit         |      30000 |
|        3 | 2019-02-26 | 21:10:00 |  78805 | 6979A     | deposit         |     100000 |
+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+

mysql> select * from transactions where accountno = 'A6B55' ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 1;
+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| clientid | date       | time     | CardNo | accountno | Transactiontype | curbalance |
+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
|        2 | 2019-02-26 | 18:15:00 | 865505 | A6B55     | deposit         |      30000 |
+----------+------------+----------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+
```

Have a nice day:) Cheers...

Comment: Thank you for this code I finally did it. Cheers man. Have a nice day!